# Why I couldn't use mount --bind /proc/<pid>/ns/mnt to another file in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, mount

Recently, I am learning about linux namespaces. 
I hope even if the process ends, I could still attach the namespace that process is in.
Someone told I could use `mount --bind /proc/<pid>/ns/pid ./pid` to keep this file open. So I tried it.
When I mount uts, user, ipc, pid, net... They are all okay..

```
root@ubuntu:/home/jiashenh/workspace# touch uts
root@ubuntu:/home/jiashenh/workspace# mount --bind /proc/171/ns/uts ./uts
```

But when it comes to mnt.... I used it in the same way ...

```
root@ubuntu:/home/jiashenh/workspace# touch mnt    
root@ubuntu:/home/jiashenh/workspace# mount --bind /proc/171/ns/mnt ./mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /proc/171/ns/mnt,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so
```

It failed.....So could anyone told me how to fix it?
.

Answer (score 3):

Bind mount for `/proc/<pid>/ns/mnt` really doesn't work if called within the same mount namespace.

However, bind mount for `ns/mnt` works if:

- `mount()` is called from a process with another mount namespace, *and*
- `mount()` is called from a process where the `ns/mnt` being mounted is visible.

Both requirements are met if `mount()` is called from a process forked before `unshare()` call that created `ns/mnt` entry being mounted.

(Note that *after* `unshare()` call, previously visible `ns/mnt` entries are no more visible and become broken symlinks).

Here is a test:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int fd = open("/tmp/mnt.ns", O_CREAT | O_RDWR);
    close(fd);
    if (argc > 1) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            sleep(1);
        } else {
            unshare(CLONE_NEWNS);
            wait(NULL);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    char src[PATH_MAX] = {};
    snprintf(src, sizeof(src), "/proc/%u/ns/mnt", (unsigned)getppid());
    if (mount(src, "/tmp/mnt.ns", NULL, MS_BIND, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("mount failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("mount ok\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This test fails without `fork()` and `unshare()`:

```
$ sudo ./a.out  
mount failed: Invalid argument
```

But works if it calls `fork()` and `unshare()` before `mount()` (note the `x` arg):

```
$ sudo ./a.out x
mount ok
```

See [this commit](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/c84f2590dfdb8570beeb731e0105f8fe597443d1) for `unshare` tool and also [this patch](http://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/containers/2013-August/033386.html).

Unfortunately, this behaviour specific to `ns/mnt` is not documented in [`namespaces(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html).